# How can I give two compatible names to a C++ class template with deduction guides?

Tags: c++, c++17, ctad

If I have a widely-used class template called `Foo` that I want to rename to `Bar` without having to update all of its users atomically, then up until C++17 I could simply use a type alias:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Bar {
 public:
  // Create a Bar from a T value.
  explicit Bar(T value);
};

// An older name for this class, for compatibility with callers that haven't
// yet been updated.
template <typename T>
using Foo = Bar<T>;
```

This is very useful when working in a large, distributed codebase. However as of C++17 this seems to be broken by class template argument deduction guides. For example, if this line exists:

```cpp
template <typename T>
explicit Foo(T) -> Foo<T>;
```

then the obvious thing to do when renaming the class is to change the `Foo`s in the deduction guide to `Bar`s:

```cpp
template <typename T>
explicit Bar(T) -> Bar<T>;
```

But now the expression `Foo(17)` in a random caller, which used to be legal, is an error:

```cpp
test.cc:42:21: error: alias template 'Foo' requires template arguments; argument deduction only allowed for class templates
  static_cast<void>(Foo(17));
                    ^
test.cc:34:1: note: template is declared here
using Foo = Bar<T>;
^
```

**Is there any easy and general way to give a class with deduction guides two simultaneous names in a fully compatible way?** The best I can think of is defining the class's public API twice under two names, with conversion operators, but this is far from easy and general.

Comment: You get some of the conversions for free if you derive the old class from the new class. But there's no perfect solution if your API users have mixed `auto&` and `Foo&`, which is quite possible in an older code base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what [P1814R0: *Wording for Class Template Argument Deduction for Alias Templates*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html)
wants to solve, that is to say, in C++20, you only need to add deduction guides for `Bar` to make the following program well-formed:

```
template <typename T>
class Bar {
 public:
  // Create a Bar from a T value.
  explicit Bar(T value);
};

// An older name for this class, for compatibility with callers that haven't
// yet been updated.
template <typename T>
using Foo = Bar<T>;

template <typename T>
explicit Bar(T) -> Bar<T>;

int main() {
  Bar bar(42);
  Foo foo(42); // well-formed
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/zYxxabdb4)

But since it is a C++20 feature, there is currently no solution in C++17.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Unfortunately clang doesn't yet implement P1814R0. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define a macro?

```
#define Foo Bar;
```

(Personally I'd find it confusing with multiple names for same implementation, but I'm not you.)

Sorry I can't test at the moment, but I hope it works!

Comment: Seriously, no. That breaks all kind of things. Macro's don't obey name spaces.

Comment: I'm really surprised I didn't consider this actually. The name happens to be unique enough that this might not be a _terrible_ idea as a very temporary hack. Thanks.