# Is it possible to make CTAD accept template type alias?

Tags: c++, containers, c++17, ctad

C++ introduced class template argument deduction so instead of

```cpp
std::array<int, 33> arr{1,2,3,...};
std::vector<float> vec{0.0, 0.1, 0.01, ...};
std::pair<int, float> pair {1, 1.1};
```

we can write cleaner code

```cpp
std::array arr{1,2,3,...};
std::vector vec{0.0, 0.1, 0.01, ...};
std::pair pair {1, 1.1};
```

But, when we make a type alias with the same template parameters deduction fails for some reason

```cpp
#include <array>
template<class T, size_t N>
array_alias = std::array<T, N>;

int main() {
  array_alias array {1,2,3}; // expected array_alias<int, 3>
  return 0
}
```

I've expected it will use same deduction method, but for some reason every compiler throws an error. What's the difference with alias template and class template and is there a way to make it work?

Comment: See [Deduction_for_alias_templates (C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Deduction_for_alias_templates).

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69342182/how-can-i-give-two-compatible-names-to-a-c-class-template-with-deduction-guide/69342585#69342585

Comment: @Jarod42 so basically it's should be fixed in c++20?

Comment: @Sugar: Yes, it should be.

Comment: @Sugar: It’s not a “fix”—CTAD for alias templates (which need not be as trivial as this one) is a sophisticated, complicated feature that was added when it was ready.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes. you can close mine question as dupe.

Comment: @DavisHerring c++14 also did compicated things, but mostly it was behavior fixes of what c++11 introduced, CTAD was introduced in c++17 and alias templates deduction proposal basically is a fix of template deduction behavior.

Comment: @Sugar: I would definitely not call it a “fix”—it has significant additional expressive power despite being restricted to a certain form of alias template and comes with what may be the longest example in the entire standard (a full page).